# import rasterio gives DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found error

Tags: gdal, error, import, rasterio

I tried pip install rasterio but it failed building a wheel. So i downloaded the wheel file and tried installing it again as suggested in this post:
https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/603
It worked and rasterio-1.0a12 was installed successfully but when I am importing it in python it gives me this error:
DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

As suggested in this site https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rasterio , i added gdal111.dll and gdal-data file path to windows path but the same error persists. Any suggestions?

Comment: the instructions in the last comment of https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/603 are erroneous and I have deleted them.

Comment: See related question and answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/293398/113835

Answer (score 3):

You can not `pip install rasterio` on Windows. There are no binary wheels for Windows on the Python package index. You must use the binary wheels published by Christoph Gohlke (as explained in the rasterio readme), or use Anaconda and the conda-forge packages.

Comment: i had downloaded the wheel from that website and then installed it, yet it shows the same error

Comment: Did you see at https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rasterio that the rasterio wheel depends on the GDAL 2.2.3 wheel (https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal)? The GDAL wheel must be installed, too. That's where the DLL is found.